# Flume agent: How flume agent gets data from a webserver located in different physical server

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am trying to understand Flume and referring to the official page of flume at flume.apache.org

In particular, referring to [this section](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#data-flow-model), I am bit confused in this.

Do we need to run the flume agent on the actual webserver or can we run flume agents in a different physical server and acquire data from webserver?

If above is correct, then how flume agent gets the data from webserver logs? How can webserver make its data available to the flume agent ?

Can anyone help understand this?

Answer (score 2):

The Flume agent must pull data from a source, publish to a channel, which then writes to a sink.

You can install Flume agent in either a local or remote configuration. But, keep in mind that having it remote will add some network latency to your event processing, if you are concerned about that. You can also "multiplex" Flume agents to have one remote aggregation agent, then individual local agents on each web server.

Assuming a flume agent is locally installed using a Spooldir or exec source, it'll essentially `tail` any file or run that command locally. This is how it would get data from logs.

If the Flume agent is setup as a Syslog or TCP source (see Data ingestion section on network sources), then it can be on a remote machine, and you must establish a network socket in your logging application to publish messages to the other server. This is a similar pattern to Apache Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have mentioned --> "see Data ingestion section on network sources" , which book or reference are you referring to? Could you please elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: "network streams". Same page you have linked. https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#network-streams

Comment: I still have one doubt:  Suppose I have a physical server (say phy-ser-A) which runs Apache httpd , and say httpd logs to a file /var/logs/apache/htttpd/application.log . We haven't done any modification to httpd, that is it logs only on the local file system in which httpd is running. Now, how will a remote flume agent get the logs of httpd? I am not able to understand this. Even if we run an agent of phy-serv-A, how will the agent get the logs from httpd? Can you help understand how these scenarios are achieved?

Comment: You run Flume agent to point at that log file. You can *optionally* send your *local Flume agent data* to a remote one

Comment: Alternative technologies to this same pattern of deployment are Fluentd or Filebeat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So it means , for phy-ser-A, in which httpd is running and logging at /var/logs/apache/httpd/application.log , we can have local flume agent phy-ser-A-flume-agent, it point to directory /var/logs/apache/httpd/, so that any changes happening in this directory, it can send to other flume agent, running in phy-ser-B, and which can consolidate data to HDFS. Is this correct?

Comment: The only reason you would run a remote Flume agent at all is if **1)** You aggregated more than one web server logs before uploading to HDFS (See "Flume topology design" and "multiplexing the flow" sections. ) or **2)** The web server cannot directly access HDFS over the network, but can reach an "edge node" running said remote Flume agent server